# Is it possible to serve a web page from a self hosted web API in a windows service?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I have a perfectly normal (TopShelf hosted) windows service. I have a requirement for a simple interface to the service which will return some current stats (held in memory).

I had a cunning plan to self-host a website within the service, and I see that the asp.net API has a self host functionality.

Is it possible to subvert the 'API'ness of the system and have it return simple (though not static) HTML that a browser could read directly?

If not that are there any other options or ideas for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  This test site http://www.hypermediaapi.com is done using self-hosted WebAPI.  The source for it is here https://github.com/darrelmiller/HypermediaApiSite

Comment: @kubal5003 There is an MVC project and a Console project that uses self-host.  The Azure VM that hosts the site is using the Console project as a Windows Service.